# WebDriverError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, cucumberjs

I am getting this error:
[image]

But I can't figure out how to fix it.
Could anyone give me any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chrome 67 supports chromedriver 2.38,2.39 & 2.40 and you're using 2.29 . Please update driver to latest version which is 2.40. link here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads